# how to get the current id of a post while commenting to it

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i am trying to make a post and comment section where users can post and comment.For that purpose i have 2 tables: posts,comment

in my post table there are two columns : id and posts; it goes like this:

```
    id | post
----------------------

    1  | lo;l;l
-----------------------

    2  | i am feeling well
```

in my comment table there are three columns :id,comment and post_id(***which is the id of the post where user is commenting,so that i can retrieve the comments dynamically to each post every time*** )

i managed the post section but can't figure out how to get the id of a particular post while commenting. ***i don't want any direct solution ,rather an working outline in PDO on how to do this***. Any help in this regard will be appreciated

this is what i have managed so far( it might be a little  long but it's really simple to understand.I am not providing my database query page to keep the post smaller.All i need to know how to get the particular post_id while i am commenting to it)

i haven't write the insertComment.php page which is inside the ajax call.But i want my comment insert and retrieve functionality to go there

```
<?php
      session_start();
      require_once 'myDB.php';
      if(isset($_POST['post']) && !empty($_POST['post'])){
           $post=$_POST['post'];
           $_SESSION['post']=$_POST['post'];

           try{
               $newComment=DB::getInstance();
               $newComment->insert('post',array('posts'=>$post));
              }catch(Exception $e){
                 echo $e->getMessage();
              }
           header('HTTP/1.1 303 see other');
           header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }    
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #formdiv{width:347px;height:120px;background:#dfe3ee;position:relative;border:1px dashed black;top:0px;left:300px;padding:5px; margin-bottom:3px;

    }
    #cmntbox{
        width:347px;background:#dfe3ee;position:relative;border:1px solid black;left:300px;padding:5px;
    }
    .repText{
        width:100%;background:#f7f7f7;position:relative;border:1px solid black;padding:3px;resize:none;}
    }
</style>
</head>
</body>
<div id='formdiv'>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
        <textarea name='post' placeholder="what's on your mind !" cols='40' rows='3'></textarea>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='post comment' style='float:right;width:100px;height:30px;background:#3b5998;color:white;'>
    </form>
</div>
<?php 

      $newComment=DB::getInstance();
      $results=$newComment->getComment('SELECT','post','posts')->result();

      foreach($results as $result=>$val){
?>
    <div  id='cmntbox'><?php 
         echo $val->posts;
         echo '</br><hr>';?>
         <form>
             <textarea name='myrep' id='myreply' class='repText'></textarea>
             <input type='button' class='reply' value='reply' style='width:50px;height:30px;background:#3b5998;color:white;' >
         </form>
    </div>
<?php 
      }
?>
<script>
   var reply=document.getElementsByClassName('reply');
   var repText=document.getElementsByClassName('repText');
   for(i=0;i<reply.length;i++){
       (function(i){
            reply[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
                  var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                      if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
                           //do nothing
                      }else{
                           alert('there was a problem ');
                      }

                  }  
                  var parameters='myrep='+document.getElementById('myreq').value
                  xmlHttp.open("POST", "insertcomment.php", true);
                  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                  xmlHttp.send(parameters);
                  }
            });
       })(i);

   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: There must be a thousand tutorials along these lines

Comment: can anyone give me some hint..i am completely in the dark here ??

Comment: Well, typically you'd select the post_id when selecting the post, and hold it within a hidden input within the form.

Comment: ya,that's fine .. what could be a proper sql query for that...? i am getting hard time for that,,,and all about selecting the post ?  how selecting the post and sql query goes together ? can you be a little more elaborate ?

Comment: Are you using the Wordpress codex?

Comment: no,,i am not using any platform like wordpress,,core php only

Comment: So what is getcomment()?

Comment: it is a method. i wrote a php class called DB in a separate php file to insert and retrieve information from database. getComment get all the recent posts from the database and show them to the user similar to the image i have provided. i didn't post it here because it is over 100 lines long.if it requires i can add it to the post

Comment: Then I suggest you edit those lines of code so that the method returns the id too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have the post id at the time when your page is being loaded so while drawing the comment box in html you can set the post id as an attribute of some html element or in hidden field

So in your case update following script

```
<div  id='cmntbox'><?php 
     echo $val->posts;
     echo '</br><hr>';?>
     <form>
         <textarea name='myrep' id='myreply' class='repText'></textarea>
         <input type='button' class='reply' value='reply' style='width:50px;height:30px;background:#3b5998;color:white;' >
     </form>
</div>
```

To

```
<div  id='cmntbox'><?php 
     echo $val->posts;
     echo '</br><hr>';?>
     <form id="<?php echo $val->postId ?>">
         <textarea name='myrep' id='myreply' class='repText'></textarea>
         <input type='button' class='reply' value='reply' style='width:50px;height:30px;background:#3b5998;color:white;' >
     </form>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div  id='cmntbox'><?php 
     echo $val->posts;
     echo '</br><hr>';?>
     <form>
         <input type="hidden" name="postId" value="<?php echo $val->postId ?>" />
         <textarea name='myrep' id='myreply' class='repText'></textarea>
         <input type='button' class='reply' value='reply' style='width:50px;height:30px;background:#3b5998;color:white;' >
     </form>
</div>
```